# Tab bar icons on retina display

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, uitabbar, retina-display

I am making an iPhone App but I can't understand why my custom tab bar icons are pixelated. They are 30x30. If I change the resolution to 60x60, for example, the icons are still pixelated but they are also incomplete.

Can you help me to fix this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: What does your code look like? Your icons should be 60x60-ish to look good on a Retina display.

Comment: please include code and image

Comment: The link above gives a 404

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't need to double the size of your non-retina images.
You need to create two separate icons `icon.png` (30x30) and `icon@2x.png` (60x60).
iOS will automatically load the right file based on the screen scale.
You can find more information about taking advantage of the retina display at this url: https://developer.apple.com/resources/high-resolution/

Comment: annoyingly this does not always work for me in xcode 6.2. sometimes an app will 'kindly' show me no icon at all on a retina display, and complain about not being able to load the '1x' version of the image. after a waste of time debugging it turns out to be a classic xcode problem of it not cleaning the old bundle on the phone or updating it at all when there are changes. this is a nasty gotcha, and it keeps stinging me even though i know it is there. be aware of this. doing a full clean build and deleting the app from the device before testing a build is a must for reliable results.